# Laravel - Move index.php to a different folder

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am trying to use AngularJS for the front-end and Laravel for the back-end. As such, I have setup the following folder structure:

```
/app
    /app (contains Laravel)
    /bootstrap
    /vendor
    /public
       /api (want to place index.php for laravel here)
       /app (AngularJS files)
       app.js
       bootstrap.js
       index.html
```

And so I was hoping that by calling `/api/myController/` I would get access to myController within the Laravel framework. However, when I call `/api/` I get the following error:

> The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that, and make changes in the `index.php` file and possibly in the `start.php` file on where to load the other files from, but you'd need to make sure any time you updated laravel you fixed up any references.

Why not just move the entire laravel application to inside the api folder?

Comment: I did do that. I made sure the directories all match up. If I call `/api/index.php/myResource`, then it works fine, but I need to explicitly type in the `index.php` and I don't want that!

Comment: in that case, it should be a simple `htaccess` file that you need to pop in your api folder, like what is in stock laravel public folder

Comment: Surely moving the entire laravel application is a security risk. Ideally you want it outside public access.